# Как на Python'е в исходный текст вставить html-ссылку

Tags: html, python

У меня есть скрипт написан на Python'е, который рассылает письма на почту.
И я хочу, чтобы в тексте письма до одного слова была прикреплена ссылка на другой сайт.
То есть, когда пользователь читает письмо и нажимает на слово (например ссылка), он переходит на мой сайт.
Как это можно сделать на Python'е?

Comment: Питон не при чем. Рассылайте html-письмо.

Comment: [Вот (более сложный) пример](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19171742) как в Питоне послать письмо, содержащее простой текст (для людей, отключающих HTML в почтовых клиентах) и HTML со встроенной картинкой. Только `<a href="..">ссылку</a>`  гораздо проще добавить. Можно `MIMEText('<a>..', 'html')` даже без `MIMEMultipart()`) использовать.

Comment: Подскажите еще по примеру ниже
<a href="http://tes.kl.com.ua" target="_blank"> <img src = "http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-lo .." > </a>

когда приходит письмо на почту то картинки нет. Вместо нее квадратик с значком поврежденного файла

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте `html` в письмо

Например:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
     <a href="http://mywebsite.com">myWebsite</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Подскажите еще по примеру ниже
<a href="http://tes.kl.com.ua" target="_blank"> <img src = "http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/ubuntu-lo .." > </a>

когда приходит письмо на почту то картинки нет. Вместо нее квадратик с значком поврежденного файла